# Fonts and different glyphs

Tags: fonts, unicode, truetype-fonts

I was always curious about how to create nonstandard fonts and couldn't find a good documentation how the font mechanism works.

How come the screen is rendering this? If this is a Unicode, how can I create fonts like this example:

an​*̶͑̾̾​̅ͫ͏̙̤g͇̫͛͆̾ͫ̑͆l͖͉̗̩̳̟̍ͫͥͨe̠̅s

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Unicode character set contains the concept of [Combining characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_character) :

> combining characters are characters that are intended to modify other
> characters

When copying the above text and displaying it with notepad++, one gets :

[image: text]

The text string contains no less than 38 characters, where most are combining ones.
For example, one can find the character [COMBINING LEFT HALF RING ABOVE](http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode6.2.0/)
which looks like:

[image: half ring]

These combining characters, mostly intended for use in complex Asian languages,
can also be used creatively as decoration for Latin characters, which is what was done here.

From [Unicode 6.2](http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode6.2.0/), [chapter 2](http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode6.2.0/ch02.pdf):

> All combining characters can be applied to any base character and can, in principle, be used with any script. As with other characters, the allocation of a combining character to one block or another identifies only its primary usage; it is not intended to define or limit the range of characters to which it may be applied. *In the Unicode Standard, all sequences of character codes are permitted.*
>
> This does not create an obligation on implementations to support all possible combinations equally well. Thus, while application of an Arabic annotation mark to a Han character or a Devanagari consonant is permitted, it is unlikely to be supported well in rendering or to make much sense.